# Picking a time based on when the app was last used

Tags: datetime, typescript, browser-storage

I am trying to set up a time variable as a local storage property to be retrieved when I open my app in my browser.

If I open it **for the first time, today,** I'll set it up to **today at midnight**.

Otherwise, if the time property **has already been set up today in a previous session**, I'll provide the retrieved value to the session, and assign `Date.now` to the local storage property for next time I'll visit my app.

I am trying to use *ternary operators* in place of *if statements*, but I see duplicated code I am not able to avoid. I am sure I am missing a trivial logic error, but I am not seeing it right now.

```
const NotificationsStorage: { lastCheck: number } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('NotificationsStorage'));
const today: number = moment().startOf('day').valueOf();
const now: number = moment().valueOf();

localStorage
    ? NotificationsStorage
        ? (NotificationsStorage.lastCheck && NotificationsStorage.lastCheck > today)
            ? (
                this.lastCheck = NotificationsStorage.lastCheck,
                localStorage.setItem('NotificationsStorage', JSON.stringify({ lastCheck: now }))
            )
            : (
                localStorage.setItem('NotificationsStorage', JSON.stringify({ lastCheck: today })),
                this.lastCheck = today
            )
        : (
            localStorage.setItem('NotificationsStorage', JSON.stringify({ lastCheck: today })),
            this.lastCheck = today
        )
    : console.warn('Current browser doesn\'t support Local Storage API');
```

Comment: Is there a reason you are using ternary operators? If this will be production code, I would highly discourage nested ternaries of any sort as they're practically unmaintainable and the linter even warns you about it: https://eslint.org/docs/rules/no-nested-ternary

Comment: Hi @SrdjanGrubor , thanks for the comment, and for pointing out the issue of nested ternary operators.
No specific reason at all, just trying to learn them, but I can easily see the issue of nested ternary operators.
What would you suggest? Classic `if/else` statements?

Comment: Yes, classic if/else is almost always encouraged since it's easy to visually parse and maintain. As a sidenote, whatever speed it might seem that you're gaining with the ternary, the interpreter will most likely make that negligible of a difference but you lose almost all maintainability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whether you use ternaries or classic if/else you can often make your nesting easier to read by inverting your conditions. i.e.

```
! window.localStorage
    ? console.warn('Current browser doesn\'t support Local Storage API');             
    : NotificationsStorage
    && NotificationsStorage.lastCheck 
    && NotificationsStorage.lastCheck > today
        ? (
            this.lastCheck = NotificationsStorage.lastCheck,
            localStorage.setItem('NotificationsStorage', JSON.stringify({ lastCheck: now }))
        )
        : (
            localStorage.setItem('NotificationsStorage', JSON.stringify({ lastCheck: today })),
            this.lastCheck = today
        )
```

Although you can't do it with a ternary operator, I also usually prefer to use early returns to limit nesting. This also avoids the issue that you access localStorage in your first line even though it might not exist.

```
if (! window.localStorage) {
  console.warn('Current browser doesn\'t support Local Storage API');  
  return;
}

const NotificationsStorage: { lastCheck: number } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('NotificationsStorage'));
const today: number = moment().startOf('day').valueOf();
const now: number = moment().valueOf(); 

if (NotificationsStorage
    && NotificationsStorage.lastCheck 
    && NotificationsStorage.lastCheck > today) {
      this.lastCheck = NotificationsStorage.lastCheck,
      localStorage.setItem('NotificationsStorage', JSON.stringify({ lastCheck: now }))
 } else { 
      localStorage.setItem('NotificationsStorage', JSON.stringify({ lastCheck: today })),
      this.lastCheck = today
}
```

You could simply that last `if` by separating the variables and the logic to update them:

```
const {newStoredValue, newLocalValue} = 
    NotificationsStorage
    && NotificationsStorage.lastCheck 
    && NotificationsStorage.lastCheck > today 
    ? [now, NotificationsStorage.lastCheck]
    : [today, today];

 localStorage.setItem('NotificationsStorage', JSON.stringify({ lastCheck: newStoredValue }));
 this.lastCheck = newLocalValue;
```

Answer (score 0):

OK, I believe I found the solution. I was checking for something that was, instead, part of the bundle of conditions without which I would not been able to set up a `lastCheck` at all, so I put them together, hopefully, avoiding repetition.

Please, feel free to post a better solution. I would love to see it and learn.

```
const NotificationsStorage: { lastCheck: number } = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('NotificationsStorage'));
const today: number = moment().startOf('day').valueOf();
const now: number = moment().valueOf();

localStorage
    ? NotificationsStorage
    && NotificationsStorage.lastCheck 
    && NotificationsStorage.lastCheck > today
        ? (
            this.lastCheck = NotificationsStorage.lastCheck,
            localStorage.setItem('NotificationsStorage', JSON.stringify({ lastCheck: now }))
        )
        : (
            localStorage.setItem('NotificationsStorage', JSON.stringify({ lastCheck: today })),
            this.lastCheck = today
        )
    : console.warn('Current browser doesn\'t support Local Storage API');
```